# simple isPrime function from a tutorial doesn't work

Tags: java

System.out.pritnln does not print out anything from the following code:

I'm new to this so I don't really see what the problem is. It worked for the guy from the tutorial that I'm following. I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.2

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     int count = 0;
     for (int i = 10; i < 50; i++) {
         if (isPrime(i)) {
             count++;
             System.out.println("Number " + i + " is a prime number");
             if (count == 3) {
                 System.out.println("Exiting the loop");
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
 }

 public static boolean isPrime(int n) {  
     if (n == 1) {
         return false;
     }
     for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++) {
         if (n % 1 == 0) {
             return false;
         }
     }
     return true;
 }
```

Comment: `if (n % 1 == 0)` this is always true. Every integer is divisible by 1...

Comment: @tkausl add as an answer

Comment: Looks like a misprint. Should be `n % i == 0`

Comment: Like I said I'm new to programming. Got it fixed thanks

Comment: Lol, its because isPrime() is not actually prime

Comment: For verifying if a number is prime you only have to go up to the ceiled square root of the base number. Drastically decreases compute time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in your `isPrime` function.
The way it is constructed now it will always return `false`.

You have to replace

```
if (n % 1 == 0)
```

with

```
if (n % i == 0)
```

Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in this function  `public static boolean isPrime(int n)` 
in what inside the condition : `if(n==1)` this is always truth !!

for that you have to change to `if(n==i)` :

```
public class Try0 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    int count = 0;
            for (int i = 10; i < 50; i++) {
                if (isPrime(i)) {
                    count++;
                    System.out.println("Number " + i + " is a prime number");
                    if (count == 3) {
                        System.out.println("Exiting the loop");
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     public static boolean isPrime(int n) {  

            if (n == 1) {
                return false;
            }
            for (int i = 2; i <= n / 2; i++) {
                if (n % i == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

}
```

**Output :**

```
Number 11 is a prime number
Number 13 is a prime number
Number 17 is a prime number
Exiting the loop
```